# Confirm that it is the correct user via email link without requiring login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

For my Rails app, I would like users to be able to create a resource by clicking an email link without logging in, so that they can easily indicate from their phone that they have bought groceries.

Here is my idea for how to do this, but I'm not sure it is the best approach, and I would appreciate feedback, warnings, and recommendations. I wonder if there is a standard tool that would accomplish this better than I can, or if it makes sense to build my own simple process, as I describe below.

When the user is logged in to the site (let's say they were on the site yesterday), they click "Email me the grocery list." This generates an email containing a simple html checklist version of the grocery list, and a link that they can click once they've bought the list.

The email link will look like this: `http://example.com/list_buy?list_id=1713&user_id=182&list_buy_code=c5b222fdd3134ba05a062cc2273db450`.

The `list_buy_code` parameter is generated by `current_user.list_buy_code`, because each user will have an attribute called `list_buy_code` which will be a `SecureRandom.hex(16)`.

When they click on the link, the action will only be completed `if params[:list_buy_code] == current_user.list_buy_code`.

Possibly, the email would say that the link could only be used once, in which case the list_buy_code attribute would be regenerated each time. But since the stakes are fairly low (maliciously indicating that someone else has bought groceries?), I think I may allow users to use the link more than once / indefinitely if they find it convenient.

A bit of research led me to [Pekka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3237506/5037635) which I think validates my approach. I would appreciate if anyone could confirm or improve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only an opinion here:

As you correctly stated, there is no real hazard here, so the code can be sent by email, and nothing malicious should happen. (If you ever do something sensitive, ditch plaintext, and preferably ditch SMTP altogether)

Your approach is valid, just providing insight how I would approach this.

My approach would be to create a table with buy codes. This should store user_id, list_id (based on your question), completed value, and the hash. You could ditch the user_id though, because I somehow expect list to store the user. You could also store the ip and user agent used to load the link.

Nevertheless, you then generate email with only *?list_buy_code=[hash]*
You can then relatively easily find ex. `ListBuyCode.where(:hash => params[:list_buy_code]).first`, and get to everything you need to complete the list.

This way you minimize the chance someone will repeatedly mess with your users list, while still providing the functionality you wanted.

Just an idea though.

If I'm mistaken please let me know.

Comment: Thank you! I like the idea of a new table. I am not ditching user_id because I want users to be able to 'buy' other users' lists. Basically the act of 'buying' creates a new object (ListBuy) that stores all the attributes of the list at the moment of 'purchase' (price, etc.). Anyway, appreciate your help and suggestions!