# PHP / Mail / MySQL: Email Confirmation for Register

Tags: php, mysql, email

I'm not familiar with PHP / MySQL and Emails. And I'm pretty sure this question has been asked somewhere already, but I cannot find it. So I apologise if this is troubling and thank you in advance!

Is it possible to do something that user has to click on a link in email first before the user is added into database???

And you know how, for some websites, they have a unique web address for each email validation (Shown in red on the picture)? How do they create a webpage that's unique in for every email ?

Picture credited: https://kayako.atlassian.net/wiki/download/attachments/5734920/subs-validation.png?version=1&modificationDate=1291956283000&api=v2

[image]

Thank you a lot for the attention! If it's possible, I prefer not having straight scripts that I can copy and paste because I like to find out myself :P But please do give me some hints because I'm totally lost.

If there's anything that's not clear, please tell me, I'll try my best to clarify it!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088969/generating-confirmation-code-for-an-email-confirmation   visit this

Comment: Very good question. You could build the link simply as `example.com/activate.php?code=a2ef24...` as I do in my answer below. the URLs formatted as you see are rewritten to look just like that behind the scenes, using `.htaccess` rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The Registration process**

1. User fills out a form online with basic details including an email and password, and submits the form to `register.php`
2. `register.php` adds user info to a temporary location, such as a `pending_users` table which has all the fields the user submitted along with an `expiration` and an `activation_code` fields. This code can be any random, impossible to guess value. eg: `hash('sha1', mt_rand(10000,99999).md_rand(10000,99999))`. Just don't do anything predictable such as hash the current time, or the username
3. `register.php` sends an email to the user with a URL that will link to `activate.php` and that includes the activation code. eg: `example.com/activate.php?code=a2ef24...` The email should also inform the user of the expiration (1 to 12hrs validity seems ok to me)
4. When user clicks the link, she triggers a `GET` request to `activate.php`. In doing so, the user proves ownership of the email address
5. `activate.php` gets the code from the request parameters, eg: `$code=$_GET['code']`. With that code, the script queries the `pending_users` table for the record matching that code.
6. If the code is found, check that it hasn't expired before proceeding. Expiration prevents someone else much later who gets in the user's account from completing the registration.
7. If the code is valid, capture the user details from the matching record and delete that record from `pending_users` table.
8. Write a matching record in the regular `users` table. Until this is done, the user could not log in because login script only checks the `users` table, and ignores the `pending_users` table.
9. Registration complete.

**Security Note I:**

For your users' protection, never store passwords in cleartext. When you receive it from the registration form (eg: `$_POST['pwd']`, do:

```
$pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

//first validate; it should meet minimum requirements

$pwd_hash = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // <- the hash gets stored
```

Later, to verify the password, do:

```
password_verify($cleartext_pwd, $pwd_hash);
```

It will return `true` if the password is correct; `false` otherwise.

**Security Note II:**

For your protection, *never* insert user supplied values directly in your DB queries.  This means *any* value that arrives from the outside. Not just usernames, emails, passwords... but also values that you're getting back from the user such as `activation_code` above or cookie values or headers (eg User-Agent). Instead, learn to use *prepared statements*.  This will protect you from SQL injection.

Comment: On the email that I send: the link that directs to the validation page is:  http://localhost:8888/Brighten/admin/signup/validation.php?salt=cd16136f697c7264
But when I actually click on it, it becomes like: http://localhost:8888/Brighten/admin/signup/validation.php?e6fc0ac809033f41
Why do they get rid of my GET function?

Comment: Without more info I cannot say. if I were you, I would confirm the error first.  Make sure that the script is actually receiving the request; then do `print_r($_GET)` to double-check that the activation code is not shown.  If that's really the case, open a new question and ask about it.

Comment: Thank you, it's a very good guide! I have one question though. Why not insert unconfirmed users into main users table and marking them as unconfirmed so they can still log in but with restricted permissions? I got locked out as a user once, having messed up email confirmation. I had to register with another email then get the customer support to manually delete my first account with unconfirmed email so that I can change my temporary email to my main email in the second account. It cost both of us quite a bit of time.

Comment: @ArthurTarasov that makes sense too, if you want to allow logins.  Or your login script could also look in the pending users table and allow login from there, but set restricted permissions.  In my own implementation, if the email validation is never completed, the pending record is deleted so you would have been able to attempt registration with same email later on, but with a new validation code.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's possible to add datas in database after the validation...

When I want to do something like that, I create a data in the users table (or metas users table) like "validate".
If this data is "true", then the user already did the validation and he can use his account. If it's still set on "false", the user didn't validate his account : he can't use it.

With that, you have to make sure the account is validate when the user tries to log in, but it's not a big deal ^^

Hope it's usefull.

Comment: That's very useful, and that's a nice and simple way to do it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Those are not a unique websites, there is only one script validating the registration finalization. The incoming requests (when the user has clicked the link) are routed all to the same script by means of server side "request rewriting", so that the random token value is available as an argument (parameter) to the script execution.

What the script does: it checks if that random token value does exist in the database where it has been generated and stored before when the user actually registered.

The only thing left to do for that script is to remove the confirmation random token and/or set a flag indicating that the registered use has actually confirmed his identify (email address) by clicking the link.

Easy and straight forward. Hard to bypass, since you cannot guess what random token value has been generated for what registered user without receiving the email. However take into consideration that it is trivial for an attacking script to use anonymous email services (one time email addresses) to receive and evaluate such a confirmation request, if the process is known to the attacker.

Comment: So create a script which creates a hash value whenever a user registered, when user click on the address on the mail, it takes away the confirmation hash??

Comment: I replaced "hash" with "random token" which is more appropriate, I think. Yes, the script typically removes that token, since it is not required any more, _if the token has been correctly submitted during the confirmation step_. BTW: you can reuse that database column later when you offer a "forgot password" feature: you create a _new_ token and send that out the the email address again to allow a one time login for the user so that he can reset his password.