# gmdate('U') giving different results depending on the project

Tags: php, date

I have this project, which uses gmdate as salt for some data

```
md5($mykey. gmdate('U'));
```

I wanted to change this project's folder structure, and after moving a few files, now `gmdate('U')` always returns 1.

I cloned the original project again and `gmdate('U')` works fine. They are both in the same enviroment.

What's causing `gmdate('U')` to always return 1 whenever it's changed?

Comment: You can solve this problem by using a better salt. This is deterministic and you can easily get collisions. Use something like [`openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php) to generate better salts. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2088983/250259

Comment: @JohnConde Sadly I don't have any choice. It's not an important hash either.

Comment: @prgrm Try to use [microtime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) instead of ```gmdate('U')```. Or [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php), it also based on time in microseconds.